# ListView with dynamically loaded images - How to wait for ListView to load all images, then display the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I know that we can wait for the ListView to load, and then display it. However, in the case when we have dynamically loaded images that are being downloaded, the ListView will load but the images will not be loaded yet and so they will not appear in the ListView .

What is the accepted way of waiting for the ListView to load all images, and then display the ListView ?

I was thinking of something in the lines of sending a broadcast event, when the CustomArrayAdapter loads the last element's image, and then broadcast an event that all loading has been completed. However, this seems overly unnecessary for such a menial task.

I would appreciate any input on this.

Comment: accepted way? Do you expect the user to twiddle their thumbs while the images download?

Answer (score 1):

There is no accepted way of waiting for all images to load. It's usually a good thing to show the list immediately and to let the images load once they are visible. That way, you don't have to waste the time and bandwidth to load images that the user never scrolls to. This has its own problems, such as dealing with recycled Views, but it's a better user experience because you don't have to wait for a long time while (potentially) large images are downloaded.

If you really want to make the user wait, you should download the images in the background with an IntentService and put them in some sort of memory or disk cache (the http://square.github.io/picasso/ library will do this for you), and then send a broadcast when it's finished like you suggested. Have a look at LocalBroadcastManager!

Comment: :100: for showing the list immediately. Show a non-striking placeholder image if the target needs to be fetched from a remote cache (i.e. network).

Answer (score 0):

For a better user experience you shouldn't load all the images because it can heavily freeze the Ui normally it's better to load when user scrolls I usually recommend using Volley library for loading and caching your images check this link [Volley lib tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)